# how to use jboss deployment structure.xml in liferay 6.1.2 with jboss 7.1.1?

Tags: java, jboss, liferay-6

I am using jboss deployment structure.xml file in my web-inf folder to avoid bo jar conflict i used this file and my code is

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">   

   <dependencies>
   <deployment>
   <module name="com.rsa" slot="main" export="true"/>  
       </deployment>
   </dependencies>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I am using some jars like certjFIPS.jar,cryptojFIPS.jar,ssljFIPS.jar and module.xml file in the below path

E:\Projects\Liferay Project With JBoss Server\Development\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\jboss-7.1.1\modules\com\rsa\main

In module.xml file am using the following code

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.rsa">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="certjFIPS.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="cryptojFIPS.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="ssljFIPS.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

In my webinf/lib path i put the following jars certjFIPS,cryptojFIPS,ssljFIPS,bcm,logging,log4j-1.2.17

During run my project am facing the below error

ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"TestingJBOss-portlet-6.1.1.1.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"TestingJBOss-portlet-6.1.1.1.war\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"TestingJBOss-portlet-6.1.1.1.war\""}}}}

Please guide me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version Used : 
liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1
liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2(bundle tomcat)
tomcat-7.0.27
liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3(bundle jboss) 
jboss-7.1.1.

Step1: If you are connecting SAP BO please drop this list of jars in docroot\WEB-INF\lib   (bcm.jar,certjfips.jar,cryptofips.jar,ssljfips.jar)

Step2: Drop jboss-deplyment-structure.xml file in your docroot\WEB-INF path
    In jboss-deplyment-structure.xml you should use these following codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure >
<deployment>
<dependencies>
<module name="com.liferay.portal" slot="main" export="true"/>
</dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In this liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\jboss-7.1.1\modules\com\liferay\portal\main path 
We have to drop bcm.jar,certjfips.jar,cryptofips.jar,ssljfips.jar and this is the same jars what we used in lib path what we used in step1

Step3: Drop jboss-classloader.xml file in your docroot\WEB-INF path Snippet used in jboss-classloader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"  domain="DomainName"  export-all="NON_EMPTY"  import-all="true">
</classloading>
```

Step4: Start your project using tomcat first 
Step 5: Export your lifearay war after running your project in tomcat server
 Right click on your project Liferay->SDK->war expert it and this war file will save in this path liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\dist

Step6: Stop your tomcat 
Step 7: open cmd prompt first and Increase Java Heap size:    BY
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
Step 8: Type cd  in cmd prompt paste your jboss bin standalone.bat path or otherwise start standalone.bat manually in jboss path